# How to launch IE from C++ code and be able to get html data after web page is changed

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

Here is my problem:

I am about to implement a method (C++),with an URL argument as parameter, what this method do is to launch the default browser of windows,and visit the url; this URL leads to an page, user of this program have to fill in some info in this page,and submit, then it jump to result page,  and my method need to read and analyze this page data.

I know how to launch an browser like IE , but how to:

1. read page data to my program?
2. how my program know the page in browser is updated?

Maybe I should just write a web browser inside my program?

Comment: What is this HTML form doing? Is it saving the results of the form somewhere?

Ordinarily, I would say to have a background process that reads the updated form data from the server, but you will need to be able to know how and where that is stored - we won't know.

Why are you accessing this form, instead of getting the user to fill in this information in the program itself?

Comment: @The Forest And The Trees  Because what I am doing is customized development , the web page is some sort of a keygen, our client wont give me their interface, so I have to grab the key from web page. that's why I have to do this hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to do the IE browser automation. In which you want to launch the IE and try to fetch data from the web page.

With only C++ you can open the IE browser using shell and open the URL but you will not be able to fetch the data to your application.

I suggest you to check the documentation for [Selenium Web driver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

I check and find that currently no any framework available for C++.

If you are available to use C# or JavaScript than it can help to solve your issue.

Reference:

[Programming Languages & Frameworks](https://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp)

If you are available to use VBA than you can also refer link below for IE automation using VBA.

(1) [Automate Internet Explorer (IE) Using VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/)

(2) [IE (Internet Explorer) Automation using Excel VBA](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml)

(3) [VBA Internet Explorer Object](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/27772/internet-explorer-object)